# How can I plot multiple figure in the same line with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In my `Ipython Notebook`, I have a script produces a series of multiple figures, like this:
[image]

The problem is that, these figures `take too much space`, and I'm producing many of these combinations. This makes me very difficult to navigate between these figures.

I want to make some of the plot in the same line. How can I do it?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the fjarri's suggestion, I have changed the code and this works for plotting in the same line.

Now, I want to make them plot in different lines(the default option). What should I do? I have tried some, but not sure if this is the right way.

```
def custom_plot1(ax = None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
    y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
    ax.plot(x1, y1, 'ko-')
    ax.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Damped oscillation')

def custom_plot2(ax = None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)
    y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x2)
    ax.plot(x2, y2, 'r.-')
    ax.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Undamped')

# 1. Plot in same line, this would work
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection = '3d')
custom_plot1(ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
custom_plot2(ax2)

# 2. Plot in different line, default option
custom_plot1()
custom_plot2()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use subplots.

```
plt.plot(data1)
plt.show()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(data2)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(data3)
plt.show()
```

(This code shouldn't work, it's just the idea behind it that matters)

For number 2, again same thing: use subplots:

```
# 1. Plot in same line, this would work
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1, projection = '3d')
custom_plot1(ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
custom_plot2(ax2)

# 2. Plot in same line, on two rows
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,15))                  # Changed the size of the figure, just aesthetic
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1, projection = '3d')     # Change the subplot arguments
custom_plot1(ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)                        # Change the subplot arguments
custom_plot2(ax2)
```

This won't display two different figures (which is what I understand from 'different lines') but puts two figures, one above the other, in a single figure.

Now, explanation of subplot arguments: `subplot(rows, cols, axnum)`
`rows` would be the number of rows the figure is divided into.
`cols` would be the number of columns the figure is divided into.
`axnum` would be which division you're going to plot into.

In your case, if you want two graphics side by side, then you want one row with two columns --> `subplot(1,2,...)`

In the second case, if you want two graphics one above the other, then you want 2 rows and one column --> `subplot(2,1,...)`

For more complex distributions, use `gridspec` http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

Comment: Great. But I'm using custom plot function, what should I make the function return? to combine it with `plt.plot()` and `subplot()`? See my update.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the stateless API then, that is create the figure as `fig = plt.figure()`, subplots as `s = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)` and then pass `s` to your functions that will plot there without caring whether it is a subplot or not.

Comment: Same as @fjarri. pass an argument to your function.

Comment: @fjarri, I'm sorry, but what do you mean by stateless API? Is there any example that I can look at?

Comment: And I've update my question. If its possible to plot a 3d and 2d in the same line?

Comment: I pretty much explained it in my comment. A call to `plt.plot()` creates a figure and an Axes object behind the scenes; with `plt.figure()` and `add_subplot()` you have control over these objects and can pass them to functions. Most examples in the `matplotlib` gallery mix these two APIs, which makes things very unclear. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut2.html) for more details.

Comment: @fjarri, thanks! I understand that I should make the plot using `ax`. Now, how can I make the default option as plotting them seperately? I think I should automatically create a `figure` and `ax`, but I didn't figure it out.